# How do i solve this error created while i was installing a blog plugin?

Tags: error

There has been an error processing your request

> `Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons`.

Error log record number: **950942407820**

Comment: You have to enable the PHP errors so you can see what is really going on. See the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022658/7099773. Please post your correct error when you have enabled PHP errors (don't forget to disable the exception printing when putting the webshop live) or as @GeethikaAntony mentioned !

Comment: Please check the file and can you paste the issue here?

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

To find the exact error message,

1) Rename file pub/errors/local.xml.sample to pub/errors/local.xml

or
You can go to var/report and get the list of error report.

2) Based on the error, you can find the solution.

3) Also, cross check the writable permission for pub/static, pub/media, app/etc/, generated and var folders.

Comment: i have renamed the local.xml already.

Comment: can you message me in skype: 23d10da237d94edb

Comment: i have the error file took it from the var/report and its too long.

Comment: In var/report folder, you can find the file with the name "950942407820". Just open the file and post the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your Magento is in `production` mode, set it to `developer` and your error should be shown, `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: @JoeReassis If you have issues with the module itself I might be able to help you , just PM me if you wish